# prevent vim from moving lines left

Tags: html, vim, macvim

I'm editing html code in Vim (actually MacVim), and I've got this very annoying problem that everytime I write two sets of html-tags on one line vim keeps moving the line to the far left, messing up all the indenting I've done manually.
E.g., `<div>....</div><!-- a comment>`. When I write the closing tag for the second element (here the comment), all line is moved back to the far left. 
I also had a problem with vim autoindenting too much, but managed to turn autoindenting off. However, the problem with doing a "reverse indent" still remains. How can I prevent this automatic moving of the text?

Comment: Please post the results of `:verbose set ai? cin? cink? cino? si? inde? indk?`  Have you had a look at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_stop_auto_indenting?

Comment: cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
  cinoptions=j1,J1
        Last set from ~/macvim/src/MacVim/build/Release/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/inden
t/html.vim
nosmartindent
  indentexpr=''
  indentkeys=o,O,<Return>,<>>,{,},!^F
        Last set from ~/macvim/src/MacVim/build/Release/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/inden
t/html.vim

One thing to note is that when I set noautoindent it doesn't prevent autoiindentation, but when I set indentexpr='' auto indentation is prevented, but still when typing the closing tag, all line is moved out to far left...

Comment: Read from your link and found the line that helped: :setl noai nocin nosi inde=   THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at [vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_stop_auto_indenting](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_stop_auto_indenting)?
                    – Jim K

Read from your link and found the line that helped: :setl noai nocin nosi inde= – Kim Annika